# why I see black box when I draw vector map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

I am trying to create a vector map using matplotlib in python
This is my code

```
x_axis = torch.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
y_axis = torch.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
x_grid, y_grid = torch.meshgrid(x_axis, y_axis)
ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.quiver(x_grid, y_grid, 1, -1)
plt.show()
```

I expect to get a vector field like so

[image]

however I get the following image
[image]

what causes this black rectangle?

thanks

Comment: Reduce the *steps* in `linspace` from 1000 to 10. The included code plots 1000x1000 arrows filling the entire canvas.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thanks, if you'd like to write an answer so I'll mark it as correct